# the store function show me error route [admin.store] not defined for store data by modal , can not know why while i done the route correctly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

[image]
when submit the data for adding new user'(إضافة موظف)' show me route not defined i using modal for submit the data expect after press submit to save the data for the new user and route i see doesnot have any error why he can not define it ?

HomeController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserDetail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
       
            if(auth()->user()->is_admin==1)
            {
                $id =auth()->user()->id;
                $userDataa=UserDetail::where('id',$id)->get();
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');

                

            }else{

                $id =auth()->user()->id;
               $userDataa=UserDetail::where('user_id',$id)->get();
              
               
               return view('home',compact('userDataa'));

               //return redirect()->route('home')->with('userDataa',$userDataa);

            }



      //  return view('home');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       /* $validator= $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|unique:users,name,',
            'email'=>'required|unique:users,email,'
                ],
                [
                    'name.required'=>' رجاء كتابة إسم للمستخدم',
                    'name.unique'=>'الإسم مكرر - رجاء إختيار إسم جديد',
                    'email.required'=>' رجاء كتابة إيميل للمستخدم',
                    'email.unique'=>' الإيميل مكرر رجاء كتابة إيميل جديد',

                ]);
                return $validator;*/

          
                $data= User::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'email '=>$request->email ,
            'password'=>$request->password,
            'is_admin'=>$request->is_admin
            
            ]);
            return $data;
           // session()->flash('add','تم إضافة اليوزر  بنجاح');

        // return redirect()->back();
           

    }

    public function adminhome()
    {
        $allUsers=User::all();
        
        return view('adminhome',compact('allUsers'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|unique:users,name,'.$id,
            'email'=>'required|unique:users,email,'.$id
                ],
                [
                    'name.required'=>' رجاء كتابة إسم للمستخدم',
                    'name.unique'=>'الإسم مكرر - رجاء إختيار إسم جديد',
                    'email.required'=>' رجاء كتابة إيميل للمستخدم',

                ]);
                
                $data=User::findOrFail($request->id);
                
                $data->update([
                    'name'=>$request->name,
                    'email'=>$request->email,
                    'is_admin'=>$request->drop_permision
                ]);
                session()->flash('update','تم تعديل المستخدم بنجاح ');
                return redirect('/admin/home');

    }
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $id= $request->id;
      
       User::find($id)->delete();
      session()->flash('delete','تم حذف المستخدم بنجاح');
      return redirect('/admin/home');

    }
    public function user_details($id)
    {
        $user_rec=UserDetail::where('user_id',$id)->get();
       // $user_id =UserDetail::where('user_id',$id)->value('user_id');
       $user_id=$id;
        return view('qa_records',compact('user_rec','user_id'));

    }
  
    
}
```

adminhome.blade.php

```
'''@extends('layouts.master')
@section('css')
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

<!---Internal Owl Carousel css-->
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<!---Internal  Multislider css-->
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/multislider/multislider.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<!--- Select2 css -->
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('page-header')
<!-- breadcrumb -->
<div class="breadcrumb-header justify-content-between">
    <div class="my-auto">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <h4 class="content-title mb-0 my-auto">قائمة الموظفين</h4><span class="text-muted mt-1 tx-13 mr-2 mb-0">/
                الكواليتى</span>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
<!-- breadcrumb -->
@endsection
@section('title')
<title> إدارة الكواليتى </title>
@endsection
@section('content')
<!-- row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-body">
        @if($errors->any())

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif

        @if(session()->has('delete'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{session()->get('delete')}}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif


        @if(session()->has('add'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>{{session()->get('delete')}}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif
        @if(session()->has('notadded'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{session()->get('notadded')}}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif

    

        <div class="row row-sm">




            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                <a class="modal-effect btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" data-effect="effect-scale" data-toggle="modal"
                    href="#modaldemo8"> إضافة موظف</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table text-md-nowrap" id="example1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="wd-15p border-bottom-0">#</th>
                        <th class="wd-15p border-bottom-0">إسم الموظف</th>
                        <th class="wd-20p border-bottom-0">الأيميل</th>
                        <th class="wd-15p border-bottom-0">تاريخ الإضافه</th>
                        <th class="wd-15p border-bottom-0"> العمليات</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                                            $i=0;
                                            ?>
                    @foreach($allUsers as $sec)
                    <?php 
                                            $i++;
                                            ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$i}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sec->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sec->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$sec->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="modal-effect btn btn-sm btn-info" data-effect="effect-scale"
                                data-id="{{ $sec->id }}" data-name="{{ $sec->name }}" data-email="{{ $sec->email }}"
                                data-is_admin="{{ $sec->is_admin }}" data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal2"
                                title="تعديل"><i class="las la-pen"></i></a>

                            <a class="modal-effect btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-effect="effect-scale"
                                data-id="{{ $sec->id }}" data-name="{{ $sec->name }}" data-toggle="modal"
                                href="#modaldemo9" title="حذف"><i class="las la-trash"></i></a>

                            <a class=" btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{route('admin.user.details',$sec->id)}}"
                                title="عرض"><i class="las la-eye"></i></a>
                        </td>


                    </tr>

                    @endforeach



                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="modal" id="modaldemo8">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h6 class="modal-title">إضافة موظف</h6><button aria-label="Close" class="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>

                        
                        <form action="{{route('admin.store')}}" method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <lable for="exampleInputEmail1">إسم المستخدم </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">


                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <lable for="exampleInputEmail1">الايميل</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="email " name="email ">

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <lable for="exampleInputEmail1">الباسوورد</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password">

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">الصلاحيه</label>
                                    <select name="is_admin" id="is_admin" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option value="0" selected>agent</option>
                                        <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn ripple btn-primary" type="submit">حفظ</button>
                                <button class="btn ripple btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                                    type="button">إلغاء</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- row closed -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">تعديل الموظف</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form action="{{route('admin.update')}}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">اسم الموظف:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">الإيميل :</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">الصلاحيه</label>
                        <select name="drop_permision" id="drop_permision" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="0" selected>agent</option>
                            <option value="1">Admin</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">تاكيد</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">اغلاق</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- delete -->
<div class="modal" id="modaldemo9">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">حذف الموظف</h6><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <form action="{{route('user.destroy')}}" method="POST">
                <!-- {{method_field('delete')}}-->
                @method('DELETE')
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>هل انت متاكد من عملية الحذف ؟</p><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">الغاء</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">تاكيد</button>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Container closed -->
</div>
<!-- main-content closed -->
@endsection
@section('js')
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/dataTables.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/responsive.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/jszip.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/pdfmake.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/vfs_fonts.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/buttons.print.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/buttons.colVis.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatable/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
<!--Internal  Datatable js -->
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/table-data.js')}}"></script>
<!--Internal  Datepicker js -->
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Internal Select2 js-->
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Internal Modal js-->
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/modal.js')}}"></script>

<script>
    $('#exampleModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var id = button.data('id')
        var name = button.data('name')
        var email = button.data('email')
        var is_admin = button.data('is_admin')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);
        modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
        modal.find('.modal-body #email').val(email);
        modal.find('.modal-body #drop_permision').val(is_admin);

    })
</script>

<script>
    $('#modaldemo9').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var id = button.data('id')
        var name = button.data('name')
        var email = button.data('email')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);
        modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
        modal.find('.modal-body #email').val(email);
    })
</script>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserDetailController;

'''/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return  redirect()->route('login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::delete('/destroy', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('user.destroy');

Route::get('/admin/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'adminhome'])->name('admin.home')->middleware('is_admin');
Route::get('/admin/user/details/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'user_details'])->name('admin.user.details')->middleware('is_admin');
Route::patch('/admin/home/update',[App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class,'update'])->name('admin.update')->middleware('is_admin');
Route::post('/admin/store',[App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class,'store'])->name('admin.store');
Route::resource('/adminUserDetails',UserDetailController::class)->middleware('is_admin');


//Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('home');
//Route::get('/admin/home', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.home')->middleware('is_admin');
'''
```

hope to find solution for this error

Comment: Hmm... You've got `->name('admin.store');` on one of your Routes, so `route('admin.store')` _should_ be available. If you run `php artisan route:list`, do you see `admin.store` in the output of that Command? Also, have you cleared any Route Caching? (i.e. `php artisan cache:clear`, assuming you're actually doing any caching)

Answer (score 0):

do you try php artisan cache:clear? and do you another routes working on homeController?

Comment: This is not an answer, this looks more like a comment.